GAN results fluctuating
I have the following GAN architecture:
import torch, os, torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import transforms, datasets, utils

class MappingNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim, style_dim):
        super(MappingNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.mapping = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(latent_dim, style_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(style_dim, style_dim)
        )

    def forward(self, z):
        return self.mapping(z)

class PixelNorm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, epsilon=1e-8):
        super(PixelNorm, self).__init__()
        self.epsilon = epsilon

    def forward(self, x):
        return x / torch.sqrt(torch.mean(x**2, dim=1, keepdim=True) + self.epsilon)

class NoiseInjection(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NoiseInjection, self).__init__()
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1))

    def forward(self, x, noise=None):
        if noise is None:
            batch, _, height, width = x.size()
            noise = torch.randn(batch, 1, height, width, device=x.device)
        return x + self.weight * noise

class MinibatchStdDev(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        batch_std = torch.std(x, dim=0, keepdim=True)
        batch_std = batch_std.mean().expand(x.size(0), 1, x.size(2), x.size(3))
        return torch.cat([x, batch_std], dim=1)

class MinibatchDiscrimination(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features, num_kernels, kernel_dim):
        super(MinibatchDiscrimination, self).__init__()
        self.T = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(num_features, num_kernels * kernel_dim))
        self.num_kernels = num_kernels
        self.kernel_dim = kernel_dim

    def forward(self, x):
        # Compute minibatch discrimination
        x = x @ self.T
        x = x.view(-1, self.num_kernels, self.kernel_dim)
        diffs = x.unsqueeze(0) - x.unsqueeze(1)
        abs_diffs = torch.abs(diffs).sum(-1)
        minibatch_features = torch.exp(-abs_diffs).sum(1)
        return minibatch_features

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, resolution, input_mask=False, minibatch_features=100, kernel_dim=5):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.input_mask = input_mask

        input_channels = 3 + 1 if self.input_mask else 3
        # Apply spectral normalization for stability
        self.from_rgb = nn.utils.spectral_norm(nn.Conv2d(input_channels, 256, kernel_size=1))

        self.blocks = nn.ModuleList()
        res = resolution
        while res > 4:
            self.blocks.append(
                nn.Sequential(
                    nn.utils.spectral_norm(nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)),
                    nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
                    nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2)
                )
            )
            res //= 2

        self.minibatch_stddev = MinibatchStdDev()

        self.intermediate_features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(4 * 4 * (256 + 1), 128),  # +1 channel from minibatch stddev
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)
        )

        self.minibatch_discrimination = MinibatchDiscrimination(128, minibatch_features, kernel_dim)

        # Final Layer
        self.final = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(128 + minibatch_features, 1),  # Append minibatch features
            nn.Tanh()  # Limit discriminator outputs to [-1, 1] for stability
        )

        self.apply(self.init_weights)

    def init_weights(self, m):
        if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d) or isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
            nn.init.xavier_normal_(m.weight)
            if m.bias is not None:
                nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)

    def forward(self, img, mask=None):
        if self.input_mask and mask is not None:
            x = torch.cat((img, mask), dim=1)
        else:
            x = img

        x = self.from_rgb(x)

        for block in self.blocks:
            x = block(x)

        x = self.minibatch_stddev(x)
        x = self.intermediate_features(x)
        minibatch_features = self.minibatch_discrimination(x)
        x = torch.cat([x, minibatch_features], dim=1)
        return self.final(x)

class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim, style_dim, resolution, output_mask=False):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.output_mask = output_mask
        self.mapping = MappingNetwork(latent_dim, style_dim)

        self.initial = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(style_dim, 4 * 4 * 512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            nn.Unflatten(1, (512, 4, 4)),
            PixelNorm()  # Pixel normalization for stability
        )

        self.blocks = nn.ModuleList()
        self.noise_injections = nn.ModuleList()
        self.to_rgb = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(256, 3, kernel_size=1),
            nn.Tanh()  # Scale outputs to [-1, 1]
        )
        if self.output_mask:
            self.to_mask = nn.Conv2d(256, 1, kernel_size=1)

        in_channels = 512
        res = 4
        while res < resolution:
            out_channels = max(256, in_channels // 2)
            self.blocks.append(
                nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
                    nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
                    nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2),
                    PixelNorm()  # Add PixelNorm
                )
            )
            self.noise_injections.append(NoiseInjection())
            in_channels = out_channels
            res *= 2

        self.apply(self.init_weights)

    def init_weights(self, m):
        if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d) or isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
            nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight, nonlinearity='leaky_relu')
            if m.bias is not None:
                nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)

    def forward(self, z):
        style = self.mapping(z)
        x = self.initial(style)
        for block, noise in zip(self.blocks, self.noise_injections):
            x = block(x)
            x = noise(x)
        img = self.to_rgb(x)
        if self.output_mask:
            mask = self.to_mask(x)
            return img, mask
        return img

# Hyperparameters
latent_dim = 128
style_dim = 512
image_size = 64  # Resolution of images (e.g., 64x64)
batch_size = 16
num_epochs = 50
learning_rate_gen = 2e-4
learning_rate_disc = 1e-4
ema_decay = 0.999  # Decay rate for EMA
gp_weight = 0.5 # Weight for gradient penalty
lambda_r1 = 0.1  # Regularization weight for generator
initial_noise_std = 0.1  # Initial discriminator input noise
final_noise_std = 0.01  # Final noise after decay
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

generator = Generator(latent_dim, style_dim, resolution=image_size).to(device)
ema_generator = Generator(latent_dim, style_dim, resolution=image_size).to(device)
ema_generator.load_state_dict(generator.state_dict())
discriminator = Discriminator(resolution=image_size).to(device)

optimizer_G = optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=learning_rate_gen, betas=(0.0, 0.99))
optimizer_D = optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=learning_rate_disc, betas=(0.0, 0.99))

scheduler_G = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer_G, T_max=150)
scheduler_D = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer_D, T_max=150)

transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((image_size, image_size)),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.2, contrast=0.2, saturation=0.2, hue=0.1),
        transforms.RandomAffine(degrees=15, translate=(0.1, 0.1)),
        transforms.RandomCrop(image_size, padding=4),
        transforms.GaussianBlur(kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.5] * 3, [0.5] * 3),
        transforms.RandomErasing(p=0.5, scale=(0.02, 0.2), ratio=(0.3, 3.3))
])

dataset_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'dataset', 'sub-data')
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root=dataset_path, transform=transform)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

output_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'output')

def gradient_penalty(discriminator, real_images, fake_images, device):
    alpha = torch.rand(real_images.size(0), 1, 1, 1).to(device)
    interpolates = (alpha * real_images + (1 - alpha) * fake_images).requires_grad_(True)
    disc_interpolates = discriminator(interpolates)
    grad_outputs = torch.ones_like(disc_interpolates)
    gradients = torch.autograd.grad(
        outputs=disc_interpolates,
        inputs=interpolates,
        grad_outputs=grad_outputs,
        create_graph=True,
        retain_graph=True,
        only_inputs=True,
    )[0]
    gradients = gradients.view(gradients.size(0), -1)
    penalty = ((gradients.norm(2, dim=1) - 1) ** 2).mean()
    return penalty

def r1_regularization(discriminator, real_images, device):
    real_images.requires_grad_(True)
    outputs = discriminator(real_images)
    grad_outputs = torch.ones_like(outputs, device=device)
    gradients = torch.autograd.grad(
        outputs=outputs,
        inputs=real_images,
        grad_outputs=grad_outputs,
        create_graph=True,
        retain_graph=True,
        only_inputs=True,
    )[0]
    penalty = gradients.pow(2).sum(dim=(1, 2, 3)).mean()
    return penalty

g_losses, d_losses = [], []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    noise_std = initial_noise_std * (1 - epoch / num_epochs) + final_noise_std * (epoch / num_epochs)  # Gradual noise decay
    for i, (real_images, _) in enumerate(dataloader):
        real_images = real_images.to(device)
        if real_images.size(0) == 0:  # Skip empty batches
            continue

        # Train Discriminator
        optimizer_D.zero_grad()
        real_images.requires_grad_(True)
        real_images = real_images + torch.randn_like(real_images) * noise_std

        z1 = torch.randn(real_images.size(0), latent_dim, device=device)
        z2 = torch.randn(real_images.size(0), latent_dim, device=device)

        mix_ratio = torch.rand(1).item()
        mixed_z = mix_ratio * z1 + (1 - mix_ratio) * z2

        fake_images = generator(mixed_z).detach()[:real_images.size(0)]
        fake_images = fake_images + torch.randn_like(fake_images) * noise_std

        real_loss = torch.relu(1 - discriminator(real_images)).mean()
        fake_loss = torch.relu(1 + discriminator(fake_images)).mean()
        gp = gradient_penalty(discriminator, real_images, fake_images, device)
        r1_penalty = lambda_r1 * r1_regularization(discriminator, real_images, device)

        d_loss = real_loss + fake_loss + gp_weight * gp + r1_penalty
        d_loss.backward()
        optimizer_D.step()


        # Train Generator
        for _ in range(3):  # Train generator three times per discriminator step
            optimizer_G.zero_grad()
            mix_ratio = torch.rand(1).item()  # Style mixing
            mixed_latent = mix_ratio * z1 + (1 - mix_ratio) * z2
            fake_images = generator(mixed_latent)
            g_loss = -discriminator(fake_images).mean()
            g_loss.backward()

            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(generator.parameters(), max_norm=10)
            optimizer_G.step()

        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(discriminator.parameters(), max_norm=10)

        g_losses.append(g_loss.item())
        d_losses.append(d_loss.item())

        if i % 100 == 0:
             print(f"Epoch [{epoch}/{num_epochs}], Step [{i}/{len(dataloader)}], "
                    f"D-Loss: {d_loss.item():.4f}, G-Loss: {g_loss.item():.4f}, "
                    f"G-LR: {scheduler_G.get_last_lr()[0]:.5f}, "
                    f"D-LR: {scheduler_D.get_last_lr()[0]:.5f}")
             
             with torch.no_grad():
                test_z = torch.randn(16, latent_dim, device=device)
                test_images = generator(test_z)
                utils.save_image((test_images + 1) / 2, os.path.join(output_dir, f"generated_step_{i}.png"), nrow=4)


    # Update EMA Generator
    with torch.no_grad():
        for ema_param, gen_param in zip(ema_generator.parameters(), generator.parameters()):
            ema_param.data = ema_decay * ema_param.data + (1 - ema_decay) * gen_param.data

    # Save generated images and models periodically
    if epoch % 5 == 0:
        with torch.no_grad():
            z = torch.randn(16, latent_dim, device=device)
            sample_images = ema_generator(z)
            sample_images = (sample_images + 1) / 2  # Rescale to [0, 1]
            os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
            utils.save_image(sample_images, os.path.join(output_dir, f"generated_epoch_{epoch}.png"), nrow=4)

        # Save models
        model_dir_gen = os.path.join(output_dir, 'checkpoints', 'generator')
        model_dir_disc = os.path.join(output_dir, 'checkpoints', 'discriminator')
        os.makedirs(model_dir_gen, exist_ok=True)
        os.makedirs(model_dir_disc, exist_ok=True)
        torch.save(generator.state_dict(), os.path.join(model_dir_gen, f"generator_epoch_{epoch}.pth"))
        torch.save(discriminator.state_dict(), os.path.join(model_dir_disc, f"discriminator_epoch_{epoch}.pth"))

    # Step the learning rate schedulers
    scheduler_G.step()
    scheduler_D.step()

# Save final generator and discriminator
torch.save(generator.state_dict(), os.path.join(model_dir_gen, "generator_final.pth"))
torch.save(discriminator.state_dict(), os.path.join(model_dir_disc, "discriminator_final.pth"))

print("Training completed.")

When I train on a batch of 100 images just to test it out, my output looks like this:
Epoch [0/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 2.5000, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [1/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 2.5000, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [2/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 2.2945, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [3/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.2880, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [4/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.4982, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [5/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.5007, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [6/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.4992, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [7/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.4939, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [8/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.4971, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [9/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.2764, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [10/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.4993, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [11/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.4992, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [12/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.5003, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [13/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.5000, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [14/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.5000, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [15/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.5000, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00020, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [16/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.5000, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00019, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [17/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.5000, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00019, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [18/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 2.5000, G-Loss: -0.9990, G-LR: 0.00019, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [19/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 2.4753, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00019, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [20/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 2.4670, G-Loss: -0.9871, G-LR: 0.00019, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [21/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 2.2677, G-Loss: -0.9488, G-LR: 0.00019, D-LR: 0.00010
Epoch [22/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.2090, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00019, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [23/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.2786, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00019, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [24/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.3120, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00019, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [25/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.3474, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00019, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [26/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.4567, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00019, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [27/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.3537, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00018, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [28/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.3916, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00018, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [29/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.2660, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00018, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [30/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.3715, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00018, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [31/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.2640, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00018, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [32/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.3432, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00018, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [33/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.3162, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00018, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [34/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.2603, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00018, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [35/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.1340, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00017, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [36/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.2660, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00017, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [37/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.5936, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00017, D-LR: 0.00009
Epoch [38/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.8096, G-Loss: 0.9763, G-LR: 0.00017, D-LR: 0.00008
Epoch [39/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 2.4998, G-Loss: -1.0000, G-LR: 0.00017, D-LR: 0.00008
Epoch [40/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 2.5080, G-Loss: -0.9832, G-LR: 0.00017, D-LR: 0.00008
Epoch [41/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 1.7576, G-Loss: 0.9975, G-LR: 0.00017, D-LR: 0.00008
Epoch [42/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.8342, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00016, D-LR: 0.00008
Epoch [43/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.7444, G-Loss: 0.4705, G-LR: 0.00016, D-LR: 0.00008
Epoch [44/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.2642, G-Loss: 0.9983, G-LR: 0.00016, D-LR: 0.00008
Epoch [45/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.3112, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00016, D-LR: 0.00008
Epoch [46/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.3192, G-Loss: 0.9999, G-LR: 0.00016, D-LR: 0.00008
Epoch [47/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.2842, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00016, D-LR: 0.00008
Epoch [48/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.2764, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00015, D-LR: 0.00008
Epoch [49/50], Step [0/7], D-Loss: 0.4195, G-Loss: 1.0000, G-LR: 0.00015, D-LR: 0.00008
Training completed.


Where am I going wrong? I don't think this is due to simply using a small dataset.

Soo.. what is your question about exactly?

@CutePoison Where am I going wrong? Why am Ik getting such terrible performance?

The losses are supposed to fluctuate. When the generator gets better the discriminator loss increases, and vice versa. Instead of looking at loss values, you need a validation metric that measures the quality of the generator outputs

@Karl What's a good metric for that?
